# redis and tags for a large video site

Tags: tags, nosql, redis

My question is regarding tags and searching, for a tube/flash based
video clip site.

I have apx 100,000 videos which I want to organize using Redis.

Each video has the following:

Title, length, tags

I've been adding the clips with the following

```
hset video:id1 title  "A funny clip"
hset video:id1 length "22 secs"
hset video:id1 tags   "funny,accident,cat"

hset video:id2 title  "Falling of a chair"
hset video:id2 length "33 secs"
hset video:id2 tags   "funny,chair,kids"

hset video:id3 title  "Pool party"
hset video:id3 length "17 secs"
hset video:id3 tags   "funny,pool,accident"
```

What do I do now to allow for searching by tags.

I'd like to be able to do a search for all the clips which have 
certain tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going the wrong way around. In redis you sort of need to think backwards. If you want to search for a certain tag, you need a mapping from tag to objects, instead of from object to tags. In Redis, you need to define your own indexes!

So if you want to be able to search for all videos with a certain tag, create a set for each tag, and add the video id's with that tag to the set.

Comment: ok, after spending a few hours reading up on this, I see now , why it's known as a 'dictionary server' -

Answer (score 2):

The best is to create a list for each tag in which you add the video id

```
rpush funny id1 id2 id3
```

EDIT:

You can find ideas about how to search for incomplete tags here :

http://antirez.com/post/autocomplete-with-redis.html

Answer (score 0):

> What do I do now to allow for searching by tags.

Redis doesn't support any type of ad-hoc data querying. Although there is a [KYES](http://redis.io/commands/keys) command which allows you to search for keys with certain pattern, it's only meant to be used for debugging or similar operations since it's performance is dependent on amount of keys in your database.

You can however create dedicated set structures for your tags, where each set would hold a collection of video IDs assigned to certain tag.